# about concatenate string in C language

Tags: c, string

I am using C++ to deal with string operation for long time but for some reason I have to write a code in C. I know that in C, I have to allocate the memory first before string operation. I am going to convert the array of integer to a big string, e.g.

```
int data[]={1, 102, 3024, 2, 3, 50234, 23} => "1,102,3024,2,3,50234,23"
```

I am using sprintf to convert each number in the array to string and use strcat to concatenate each substring

```
char *s, *output_string;
int i, N;
// N is the size of the array and given as parameter of a function
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  sprintf(s, "%d", data[i]);
  strcat(output_string, s);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I wonder to use those functions sprintf and strcat, do I have to allocate the memory first? But the number of digits of the data[i] is varied so how can I tell how much memory I should assigned in advance? Also, how can I tell how much memory in total I have to allocate for output_string in advance? Thanks

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: ^ It won't work because he hasn't allocated `s`

Comment: Yes, you need to allocate memory. If you don't know how much you'll need, either do a first pass to calculate it (sprintf can tell you, as can other methods) or give it a lot of memory to play with.

Comment: If you have gnu extensions asprintf is a huge time saver.

Comment: @KirkBackus That was meant to be a prompt to give more information in the question.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This question seems fine to me. Maybe clumsily named, but the content seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you need to allocate the memory for strings first.

Luckily, `snprintf()` gives you the ability to do this easily (for C at least).

```
char *s, *output_string;
int i, N;
// Count size for output_string
int output_size = 0;
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  output_size += snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", data[i]);
}

// Allocate space
output_string = malloc(output_size + 1);

// Now fill it
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  int new_size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", data[i]);
  s = malloc(new_size + 1); // Extra space for null terminator
  sprintf(s, "%d", data[i]);
  strcat(output_string, s);
  free(s);
}
```

Comment: C++11 also (finally) supports `snprintf`

Comment: C++03 didn't include C99, for some reason, so it's taken a while to catch up.

Comment: this looks good to me though it doesn't look straightforward. BTW, I am working with ANSI C only

Comment: In practice I'd probably use a mix of this and @JerryCoffin's answer, plus replace `strcat` with an offset pointer and `memcpy()`, but this is the 100% guaranteed to work method.

Comment: @MattBryant: In C++ you'd typically use a `stringstream` instead, which is an even bigger improvement over snprintf than snprintf is over sprintf.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to allocate space for both the intermediate and final result first.

Let's assume (for the sake of argument) that each int can result in a maximum of 10 digits of output:

```
char intermediate[11];

char *result = malloc(input_count * 11+1);

for (int i=0; i<input_count;i++) {
    sprintf(intermediate, "%d", data[i]);
    strcat(result, intermediate);
    strcat(result, ",");
}
```

If you want to badly enough, you can use `log10` to compute the number of digits that will be produced by each number, then allocate only the space necessary rather than allocating on a worst-case basis like I've done here.

Also note that in most cases, you'd probably be better off with `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, if it's available. This lets you limit the amount of output produced, ensure against overflowing the buffer you provide.

Answer (score 2):

`strcat` in a loop runs O(N<sup>2</sup>).  Even today that should be in reflexive-"nope" territory.

```
int need = 1; /* for the trailing nul */
for ( int n = 0; n < N; ++n )
        need += snprintf(0,0,"%s%d", n?",":"", data[n]);

{
        int used = 0;
        char *obuf = malloc(need);
        if ( !obuf ) return 0;

        for ( int n = 0; n < N; ++n )
                used += snprintf(obuf+used,need-used,"%s%d", n?",":"", data[n]);
        return obuf;
}
```